# Probability inequality concerning i.i.d

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X_1, X_2$ are iids and $x \geq 0$ is a variable such that $P[X_1 \geq x] \leq 1-p$ and $P[X \leq - x] \leq 1-p$, then show that $P[|X_1 - X_2| \geq \epsilon] \geq p P[|X_1| > x + \epsilon]$.

Can I get a start (or spoilers) at least? I have no idea whatsoever that I can write about my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$P(|X_1-X_2| \ge \epsilon)
\ge P(|X_1 - X_2| \ge \epsilon \text{ and } |X_2| < x)
\ge P(|X_1| > x + \epsilon \text{ and } |X_2| < x).$$

The first inequality is easy to verify.
For the second inequality, check that $|X_2| < x$ and $|X_1| > x + \epsilon$ together imply $|X_1 - X_2| \ge \epsilon$.